# --excludeCollection option in mongodump command seems to be ignored

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to perform a `mongodump` on a Mongo database in Python, excluding some collections.
My code looks like this:

```
cmd = ["mongodump", "--db", database, exclude_options, "--out", dump_directory]
print(cmd)
subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

This is the output of the `print` function:

```
['mongodump', '--db', 'my_database', '--excludeCollection=collection1.component --excludeCollection=collection2.component', '--out', './mongo']
```

This is the expected result. Note that `my_database` only contains `collection1.component` and `collection2.component`, so I expect an empty folder as a final result.

However, this is what is printed by the `subprocess.check_output function`:

```
2017-12-19T10:17:49.095+0000    writing my_database.collection1.component to 
2017-12-19T10:17:49.095+0000    writing my_database.collection2.component to 
2017-12-19T10:17:49.095+0000    done dumping my_database.collection1.component (1 document)
2017-12-19T10:17:49.095+0000    done dumping my_database.collection2.component (6 documents)
```

And this is the resulting tree:

```
.
├── my_database
│   ├── collection1.component.bson
│   ├── collection1.component.metadata.json
│   ├── collection2.component.bson
│   └── collection2.component.metadata.json
```

So it seems like the `-excludeCollection` option was ignored by the command. Is there an error somewhere?

Comment: Try --excludeCollectionsWithPrefix instead

Comment: I used fake data for the example, my collections don't necessarily have a common prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exclude_options` needs to be unpacked and passed as individual items in the command list.

```
exclude_options = ['--excludeCollection=collection1.component', '--excludeCollection=collection2.component']

cmd = ['mongodump', '--db', database, *exclude_options, '--out', dump_directory]
```

Unpacking in an assignment as done above works in `Python 3.*` versions.